# Build warnings - DevExpress

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

I have downloaded EZBlocker. It is an Spotify ads blocker open source and can be found here: http://www.ericzhang.me/projects/spotify-ad-blocker-ezblocker/

So i tried adding a form to that project. It is a DevExpress WinForm.
However when i try to build it i get a lot of warnings saying the following

***Warning  13  The primary reference "DevExpress.XtraNavBar.v14.2" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5".***

and this

***Warning  172 The primary reference "DevExpress.XtraNavBar.v14.2" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "DevExpress.XtraNavBar.v14.2" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".   EZBlocker***

I am guessing it is build in an older version of .Net Framework. Is there a solution to this rather than rewrite the entire project in a newer version?

Sorry if i am not clarifying this but it is really difficult to me to explain it since i have no idea what it is...

Comment: Actually by simpy changing project's target Framework did the trick.
Sorry for the troubles

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rewrite anything in order to change the targeted framework, just right click on the project name, click properties, and change the framework from the drop-down list.